# Connecting multiple DC Sources (DC Bus)

Tags: power, dc, interconnect, backup

I have a large area which I want to cover with camera and other low power devices. These devices are outdoors, and quite far away from where my intended main power source will be (say 400m). I'm looking to use a relatively small cable, such as 16AWG - as I have an existing conduit that I can pull this through. I aim on working on safe low voltage DC levels <60VDC (most likely around 54V).

My problem will be voltage drop (of course there are power losses) at the later loads. I was wondering if there was a way to connect a second source (maybe a battery being trickle fed from a small solar source) to this "DC Bus" that I want to create. This source would help reduce losses in the system - but also provide resiliency in that if my main supply fails, there will still be this source to keep everything running (allbeit at lower efficiency).

I've found it quite hard to find any sort of literature or official guidance on this so any advice greatly appreciated. I will most likely be using galvanically isolated DC power supplies.

Say I have a 400m stretch, with loads every 100m. For each load lets take ~100W. So at 54V, each load will require ~2A when a voltage drop is factored in. Wiring in parallel, the entire current will flow to the first load. So at 100m, 8A (4 Loads @2A each) will be drawn. This will result in a 39% or 21V drop at the first load alone (this was calculated using 16AWG copper cable). This is why the addition of a second source somewhere say in the middle would be great. Ideally, I want it to be one circuit and not two separate circuits for resiliency. I do have cable with multiple 16AWG pairs I can nip together to create a "larger" cable and thus less voltage drop.

Comment: Calculate your expected average and worst-case current consumption and take it from there. Speculating about voltage drops with no currents stated doesn't make sense.

Comment: Most likely you can connect your battery directly in parallel, but that's an electrical perspective, and there is also building code to consider

Comment: PoE cameras uses up to 48v specifically to combat voltage drop. I strongly suggest that you start with PoE cameras for that reason, they're cheap and handle most of this for you.  You can then run your 16g wire to each device to provide power if you need more range than standard Ethernet.

Comment: Sounds like PoE (power over ethernet).  This is what most surveillance cameras use. 400m on a run might be stretching it, so you will have to reconsider the design. You are free to devise whatever system you want, but the devil is in the detail with things like voltage drop, circuit protection and lightning protection. Poe has that all worked out with off the shelf solutions.

Comment: PoE is limited to ~100m so it's out of the question here (the copper conductors are too small)

@Lundin I understand your point, but if what I am seeking to do is not possible then it's a waste of an excercise. I'll add a scenario to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if using multiple wires to share the supply load is acceptable practice as per various electrical safety standards. Probably not... I would recommend to avoid it.

Comment: Ethernet data is limited to 100m, but it didn't sound like you wanted to use data (just power), so that doesn't matter here.

Comment: That is 800m of conductor (to and from) or 2624 feet, Is there any reason you cannot use larger conductors? You could in conjunction with the larger conductors bump up the voltage and use a buck converter at the load end. https://www.wirebarn.com/Wire-Calculator-_ep_41.html Without doing that your conductors will not fit in the condulet.

Comment: I will be using use fibre instead as distances are over 100m

@Gil yes the main reason for being confiuned to these conductors is that I have a large reel of it so looking to use it.  I could use a buck, but the losses are still going to be pretty high. What if I had the buck halfway along so to "regenerate" the power? I guess the only issue there would be that intially that buck will receive almost the full 54VDC as no loads will be drawing - so the buck will need to be capable of dealing with a large voltage range.

Comment: Saw your edit, I guess the 100W is spotlights?  First thought would be to get more efficient lights.  Otherwise you're going to need to either send higher voltage or get much thicker wire.  No way around that if you're looking to send a lot of power a long distance.  If there were, the power company would have figured it out a long time ago.

Comment: @user1850479 actually a mix of loads really. In some cases yes it will be a splotlight & camera, in another it may be to power a 4 port PoE switch... hence I assumed around 100W at every location. What I was thinking is not nessecarily higher voltage or thicker wire, but "boosting" the voltage back up again at say a certain distance. By this point some of the current will have already be used to power other loads, but we would have some voltage drop. Idea of boosting it back up again is to further reduce losses further down the line. Galvanically isolated DC-DC converters was my thinking